Setting a date on startup
I'd like to know if there's any way I can change the date settings on startup without root access.
I'm using Urovo DT50 and Honeywell EDA71, both with Android 10.
The problem is, these devices (and there's a lot of them in my workplace) connect to WiFi through the use of certificates, which have a period of validity.
For some reason after a loss of power (changing the battery or just discharging it to 0%), the date in Android resets itself to 01.01.1970, resulting in the device being unable to connect to the network. I want to "automate" clicking through the settings and changing the date by hand. Or if there's a way to change the default date the device goes back to, that could also fix the issue.
As I mentioned, I don't have root access so I take into account that it might be unachievable, does  anyone has any ideas?

Maybe this app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.singlebyte.timechanger
